# How to read the video recording from a camera/dash cam

Tags: android, camera

My goal is to read what ever the camera sees and perform calculations on it. In a scenario where I have a camera in my vehicle , I wish to connect to it from my smartphone via WI-FI/Bluetooth/NFC , after which I will pass the feed to an app in my smartphone which will perform some calculations on what is fed in real time. Is there a standard way to access the data which is been transferred via wi fi.

Comment: you should check your camera's API for that. Check how the camera is streaming the video.

Comment: so if the camera is made by a certain vendor I will need to get a hold of the API , is there no other way? , since the camera is connected to my device.

Comment: it is too broad. If the camera is connected over WIFI, you **probably** can get the video stream from some URL on it's IP address. But only the documentation of the camera will say which IP and URL to use. Also which format is the output in. Same thing for all other connection methods. SO basically - there is no universal way.

Comment: Well thank you for your time, if you do come up with anything more please let me know

Comment: I figured it out, I will change my approach i will carryout the process directly off the mobile devices camera, and thereby use the related API to access the feed ,after which i will perform my calculations.